# Is this correct sytntax: the slice is a semicircle **parallel** to the x axis when perpendicular to y with triangle base along the x and y axes?

Tags: calculus, analytic-geometry, cross-sections

I just took an exam and the question was this:

Find the volume where the base is a triangle with the vertices: (0,0),(4,0),& (0,4). The cross section is a semicircle and is perpendicular to the y-axis and is parallel to the x-axis.

I get everything up to the "parallel to the x-axis" part. Okay, so we are not using the z-axis for this course but isn't the cross-section parallel to the z-axis?

Okay, so I *guess* the professor was talking about was the *base* of the cross-section, not the cross-section.

I get that.

However, I have looked around the internet and in my multiple text books and I have never seen this type of problem explained as "*parallel to the x-axis*" so I want to know if this is incorrect syntax.

If the base is along the x and the y axis, how is the cross-section itself ***parallel*** to x?

Comment: The wording *is* a bit awkward. The best interpretation (as you seem to suggest) is that "perpendicular to the $y$-axis" describes the *plane* of the semicircular cross section, while "parallel to the $x$-axis" describes the *diameter* of the semicircle itself. (For a plane, "perpendicular to $y$" already guarantees "parallel to $x$ (and $z$)", so using both to describe the cross-sectional region would be redundant.) I might've phrased things like this: "Cross sections, in planes perpendicular to the $y$-axis, are semi-circles (above the $xy$-plane) with diameters spanning the figure's base."

Comment: @Blue You see, this is what confused me. I would have understood that.

Comment: @Blue I probably spelled that wrong. My spell check is British English, not U.S.

Answer (score 0):

Why not simpler

*A triangle has vertices: O (0,0),X(4,0),& Y (0,4). Find half cone volume enclosed when triangle $YOX$ (slant line and base radius) are rotated $180^0$ about y-axis.*

Comment: I'm not asking how to do the problem, I am asking if it is correct to say that the slices are parallel to the x axis.

Comment: Well, yeah, *why not* simpler is exactly what I am saying as a student. This professor seems to try to make things way more complicated than they actually are to the point that I don't even think I have really learned any of the actual concepts we should be covering (too focused on dumb stuff like this). Not to mention the fact that the slices are parallel to z and perpendicular to both x and y not parallel to x. *The base* of the semicircle runs parallel to x, *not the slice*.

Comment: Yes a problem statement should be brief and yet include all essential features.